Angular app migrated from 8 to 16. Now, after the deployment, nginx server returns 403 forbidden error for the images inside assets folder
With angular 8

everything works fine.

With angular 16

after the deployment, it gives 403 for all the images inside assets folder.
but it works fine from local.

We are using docker build and nginx server for the deployment.
Code used to access the images
<img src="assets/images/telematics/Ms_logo_white.png" alt="">

Docker file**
# base image
FROM node:16.14.0 as builder-side

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && mkdir /app && mv ./node_modules ./app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# start app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder-side /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200

# Starting server.
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
#CMD ["npm", "start"] #gives 502 bad gateway

nginx configuration used
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http { 

    server {
        listen 4200;

        # server_name  localhost;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        server_tokens off;

        location / {
           
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/index.html;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;
        add_header Permissions-Policy geolocation=*;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies master-only;

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp image/svg+xml application/javascript;
    }

}


Tried by giving relative path for the images, which is not working.


This question is similar to: How to serve images with nginx. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
